# Concurrent futures - Extracting file name along with the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have a folder of 100 images on which I am expected to perform some extraction task... in order to save time, I wanted to use concurrent.futures and it worked well.. the problem now is I am not able to map the output to the images in the folder.. (I do not know which extraction belongs to which file).. my code looks something like this:

```
def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        y=([val for val in executor.map(extract_features_new, img_list)])
    return y    
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=main()
```

is there an option for me to append the file name when it is returning the output??? Can someone help?

Comment: `executor.map` should return with the same order as the arguments `img_list` provided

Comment: is that true? what if one image is smaller and processed faster than the previous image in queue... in that case, the result order will be changed.. right??

Comment: I'm pretty certain – but if you don't want to risk it, just have the function also return the filename as part of a tuple

Comment: Yes, that must be an easy way...

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63362019/5722359) may help you?